# best way to send GPS coordinates to server?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, gps

Right first time use, be gentle.
Part of a year long college project, looking for help in the right **direction**.
Sending/receiving GPS coordinates in realtime(as near as possible) with iPhone 4's

Whats the best approach, was looking at GameKit Q&A here for communicating between phones but am i right in saying it works only on bt and wifi? No good to me iPhones will be out and about.

From what i know, Java RMI would fit this problem lovely but thats Java :-(  Send the coordinates and then have a Server Callback to multiple phones.
A server would be nice in the middle
What is the best approach when dealing with iOS?

Cheers

**extra edit:**
each of the 20 devices have to know the location of all others. thats the start of my project, the sharing of all their gps locations but in real time, as near as. this problem is like having no wheels on my car its stopping me befor i get started.
but how to communicate between all devices is my problem for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely certain what your trying to do, but the simplest way of storing something on a server would be a basic web request. (If you need more complexity, you can also use web services)

(You could possible dumb it down further with a html request, ie a get request: http://mydomain.com/page/default.aspx?gpsdata=blah&OtherData=blah)

Then to communicate from the server to the other iPhones, look into the Apple Push Notification services.

But depending on your project, maybe communicating with the server via web services may be an option also (that is, if communications occur with other phones only when the app is running).

Note, if you are not using a web server, then these suggestions will not be very useful or applicable, in that case, please explain a bit futher what technologies you want to use.

Comment: i need to have fast updating about every three or five secs
u might have a good suggestion with the web services, i will only be sending and receiving when the application running in main view. chat programs send data in real time, they use web services, do they? might have a look in that direction.

i dont have a predefined set of technologies i need to use other then its on the iphone. i mentioned servers cause i didnt know any better

see extra edited part above

Comment: just one more thing; can program java c++ vb and stuff but the web side is new so which server hosting would be the best. Windows or Linux?

Comment: if your communicating every 3 to 5 seconds then web services are the go. Chat apps may use web services, but that is not the only technology, there could be server processes that run constantly looking of tcp packets. There are many different ways of approaching it.

Comment: As for hosting, they all do the job. Depends on cost restrictions and programming languages your comfortable with.

Comment: If you want to avoid web services, then looking to tcp communication. Reading the Apple APN feedback service to get an idea of what the tcp streams and sockets do may help get a general idea.